# Copy Paste into formula as apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to run a google apps script which takes a series of importrange functions and puts them into an arrayformula query. I've successfully created a cell which actively accumulates the correct links for use in the importrange and puts it into a cell as a string. All I need the script to do is to copy that string and paste it as a formula in another cell. I can do this manually pretty easily, but I'd like to be able to set it up on a timer so it does it automatically on a certain time period.

As far as I've gotten is below and it doesn't work at all:

```
function Update Import Ranges() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source = spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell('B3').setFormula(???);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B3').activate();
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 0):

> accumulates the correct links for use in the importrange and puts it into a cell as a string

The `importrange()` function only accepts two parameters: one for the spreadsheet to read from, and another to specify which range in the spreadsheet to return. To read from several spreadsheets and/or ranges with `importrange()`, you will have to create several formulas.

Alternatively, use an Apps Script function that mimics `importrange()` but supports multiple spreadsheets and ranges, such as the [ImportMultipleRanges()](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/zw00GSAozsI/8d3XVeSebM4J) function. You could call it like this:

```
function updateDataFromOtherSpreadsheets() {
  var rangeToUpdate = "All Data!A2";
  var sourceSpreadsheetKeysRange = "Config!B2:B5";
  var sourceSpreadsheetDataRange = "Config!C2:C5";
  var add_spreadsheet_name_prefix = false;
  var add_sheet_name_prefix = false;
  var ignore_blank_rows = true;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var spreadsheet_keys = ss.getRange(sourceSpreadsheetKeysRange).getValues();
  var range_strings = ss.getRange(sourceSpreadsheetDataRange).getValues();

  var data = ImportMultipleRanges(spreadsheet_keys, range_strings, add_spreadsheet_name_prefix, add_sheet_name_prefix, ignore_blank_rows);

  ss.getRange(rangeToUpdate).offset(0, 0, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

To answer your question, you can fix the syntax errors and semantics in your function like this:

```
function updateImportrangeFormula() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const ssId = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  const rangeA1 = sheet.getRange('C2').getValue();
  const formula = '=importrange("' + ssId + '", "' + rangeA1 + '")';
  sheet.getRange('B3').setFormula(formula);
}
```